# ¿Porqué los reportes no se muestran cuando publico mi proyecto web?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, crystal-reports

Saludos, estoy trabajando en un proyecto web con asp.net, c# y Crystal Reports y me muestra el siguiente error solo cuando lo publico, si lo ejecuto desde el Visual Studio todo anda perfectamente:

Error

> No se pudo abrir la conexión. Nombre_Reporte 10372_12704_{CFC8BA14-9714-4F2E-8B31-54C79E897437}.rpt

He notado que cuando reinicio el IIS los numeros que muestra al lado del nombre del reporte cambian.

Lo he intentado todo, habilite las aplicaciones de 32bits, Reinstale CRforVS 13.0.21, y el runtime de 32 y 64 bits. 13.0.21. y revise los parámetros.

A continuación mostrare los codigos:

---

### ASP.NET

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"  MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Reportes.aspx.cs" Inherits="SisgemWeb.Paginas.Reportes" %>
<%@ Register assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" tagprefix="CR" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnCerraR" runat="server" class="btn btn-warning" Text="Cerrar" Visible="true"
                     OnClick="BtnCerraR_Click" />



            <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True" EnableParameterPrompt="False" GroupTreeImagesFolderUrl="" Height="1202px" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource2" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelView="None" ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="903px" />
            <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource2" runat="server">
                <Report FileName="Nombre_Reporte.rpt">
                </Report>
            </CR:CrystalReportSource>
            </asp:Content>
```

---

### Codigo C#

```
private void reporte()
        {
            try
            {


                ReportDocument reporte = new ReportDocument();
                ConnectionInfo coninfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                String strRutaArchivo = Server.MapPath("Nombre_Reporte.rpt");

                reporte.Load(strRutaArchivo);
                CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue("vContri", Session["CodCon"]);
                CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.SetParameterValue("vBD", "BD");
                coninfo.ServerName = "Server";
                coninfo.DatabaseName = "BD";
                coninfo.UserID = "root";
                coninfo.Password = "******";




                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reporte;
                CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                mtvAddMessageModal(ex.Message, MessageType.error);
            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra cosa, uno de los reportes tiene un subinforme, que quizás con las soluciones que me den no se resuelva ya que no muestra ese error, solo muestra los controles del report viewer y mas nada, pero solo es cuando lo publico, cuando lo ejecuto desde el Visual Studio todo anda bien.

Necesito respuesta urgente por favor. si me falto por indicar algo lo comentan.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Podrias especificar el error completo que te da?